# How to add the video tag with full width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to append the video tag with full width in `div` that id is video using javascript. Could you help me?

```js
let video = document.createElement("video")
video.width = 320;
video.height = 180;
video.style.background = "black"
document.getElementById("video").append(video);
```

```html
<html>
    <body style="background: lightgrey">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="video"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```html
<video width="100%" height="auto" controls>
  <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  message if vodeo does not show
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

with

```
#video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

in your css, the video will always use the full available width of its parent, in this case, of "container".

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a comment, but I cannot comment, so I post it as an answer.

```js
let video = document.createElement("video")
video.width = 320;
video.height = 180;
video.style.background = "black"
document.getElementById("video").append(video);
```

```css
#video video {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body style="background: lightgrey">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="video"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I hope I use javascript, not css

Answer (score -1):

Here it is:

```
<script>
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video");
myVideo.innerHTML()='
    <video id="video" controls>
      <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>';
</script>
```

But the script need to be after the creation of the `<div id="video">` tag.

Comment: you need to create the video tag not getting it by id

Comment: You are right, done